# How to add system icons for a UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

It's easy to add a custom image or a background for a `UIButton` , but there seems to be no programmatic way to set one of the following default iOS icons for a `UIButton` , I know it can be applied to navigation bar buttons, I don't need that, I want to apply it to a simple `UIButton`, any hints?

[image]

Comment: You can find those icons online! Like here: https://icons8.com

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For Swift 5 the syntax is:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "search"), for: .normal)
```

You can also set the weight of the icon by adding `SymbolConfiguration`:

```
let boldConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .bold)
let boldSearch = UIImage(systemName: "search", withConfiguration: boldConfig)

button.setImage(boldSearch, for: .normal)
```

See: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/) for available names (API column) or go to Interface Builder, select UIButton and in the Attributes Inspector select Image which will give you list of all available icons.

[image: Interface Builder icons]

Comment: You need to set @available attributes to check for iOS versions.

Comment: Nice option as we have lot many options from the system itself.

Comment: Why does this not work for me? My button just ends up empty. I have a conditional where the attempt to execute the above code will only happen if the iOS version is 13+

Comment: @BrianReinhold Try using the name "magnifyingglass"

Answer (score 3):

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    public convenience init?(_ systemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem) {

        guard let sysImage = UIImage.imageFrom(systemItem: systemItem)?.cgImage else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(cgImage: sysImage)
    }

    private class func imageFrom(systemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem) -> UIImage? {

        let sysBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: systemItem, target: nil, action: nil)

        //MARK:- Adding barButton into tool bar and rendering it.
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.setItems([sysBarButtonItem], animated: false)
        toolBar.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)

        if  let buttonView = sysBarButtonItem.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView{
            for subView in buttonView.subviews {
                if subView is UIButton {
                    let button = subView as! UIButton
                    let image = button.imageView!.image!
                    return image
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is an example of how do we use it:

```
 let button = UIButton() ;
 let systemImage = UIImage(systemItem: .trash) ;
 button.setImage(systemImage, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found 2521 system icons, as numerated values.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
@objc public extension UIImage{

    var assetName: String? {
        guard let imageAsset = imageAsset else { return nil }
        return imageAsset.value(forKey:"assetName") as? String
    }

    static var square_and_arrow_up: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
    }
    static var square_and_arrow_up_fill: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.fill")
    }
    static var square_and_arrow_down: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down")
    }
    ...
```

screenshot:
[image: screenshot]
github: [link](https://github.com/shang1219178163/SwiftTemplet/blob/develop/SwiftTemplet/UIImage%2BSystem.swift)

Answer (score 2):

Now you can just do

```
button.setImage(UIImage(.search), for: .normal)
```

Comment: I now use Swift 4 and coding for IOS 9 or above

Comment: I think this answer is missing some context

Answer (score -2):

```
var logoImage :[UIImage?] = []
// make an array of UIImage
// load image in asset and append in array
@IBOutlet weak var table1: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    logoImage.append(UIImage(named: "image0"))
    logoImage.append(UIImage(named: "image1"))
    logoImage.append(UIImage(named: "image2"))
    logoImage.append(UIImage(named: "image3"))
    logoImage.append(UIImage(named: "image4"))

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as? CustomCell{
       cell.iconImage.image = self.logoImage[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: Please comment your code !

Comment: where is the Issue?